# Python: How to limit the amount of random output I am getting to a specific amount?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

So, I have made the function

```
def randArrow():
    randArrow = ['left', 'right', 'down', 'up']
    print(random.choice(randArrow))
    clock.tick(15)
```

The function works, but it produces infinite amount of choices. How do I limit it to produce, say, 15 different choices?

Comment: I guess you are using pygame? Although this doesn't really contribute to the answer. Just so that I get your question right: You want to get a random choice of those 4 items only 15 times?

Comment: This function only makes one choice. Some other code is responsible for running this function repeatedly.

Comment: What should happen if you call it after producing 15 choices?

Comment: if you want to call the function onec and have it produce 15 random choices have a for loop. If you want the fucnction to produce one random choise when called and not respond after 15 time, have a `global count` that increments every time you call the function and if  count >= 15 don't let it call the function

Comment: @user2357112 Perhaps something else is making it run infinitely... let me revise my code and will get back.

Comment: @CodingLambdas Yes, I am using Pygame and yeah, only want it to produce 15 random items from the list instead of the infinite I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
needed_arrows = [randArrow() for _ in range(15)]
```

Is that what you meant?
Or do you want to only be able to call the function 15 times, and after that it returns something like `None` or raises an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use generators which are very handy:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def pickUp(n):
    randArrow = ['left', 'right', 'down', 'up']
    while n>0:
        yield random.choice(randArrow)
        n -= 1

def randomArrows():
   try:
      print( next(a) )
      root.after(10,randomArrows)
   except:
      pass

a = pickUp(5)
root = tk.Tk()
root.after(10,randomArrows)
```